# prestashop 1.7 ps_emailalerts and an external module

Tags: php, prestashop

FIRST OF ALL: Sorry for my not-good english. If something is not understandable let me know, and I will try to explain it better!

Good evening, I am having some issues with prestashop 1.7 and an external module.

I bought a module to add a fee on cash on delivery, this module got some e-mail variables, like {total_fee} or {total_fee_tax}. It takes this values from database, table ps_orders, values "codfee" and "codfeetax".

In standard mails (located in /themes/themename/mails/it/) the variables works properly, but with the e-mail alerts module (/modules/ps_emailalerts) that variables does NOT work at all.

I ask to the developer if he could help me and he sent me 2 functions to include in /modules/ps_emailalerts/ps_emailalerts.php

```
public static function getCodFeeByOrderID($id_order)
        {
        return Db::getInstance()->getRow('SELECT id_currency, codfee FROM ' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'orders WHERE id_order = ' . $id_order);
        }

public static function getCodFeeTaxByOrderID($id_order)
        {
        return Db::getInstance()->getRow('SELECT id_currency, codfeetax FROM ' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'orders WHERE id_order = ' . $id_order);
        }
```

and these 2 variables in the same file

```
        '{total_fee}' => $this->getCodFeeByOrderID((int)$params['order']->id),
        '{total_fee_tax}' => $this->getCodFeeTaxByOrderID((int)$params['order']->id),
```

But unfortunately, something don't work properly! Testing it I see that both variables give the same result "1" instead of the expected "€4" for {total_fee} and "€0.88" for {total_fee_tax}

What's wrong?
I hope that somebody help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all, you should consider overriding the ps_emailalerts module class to add the functions and keep a clean native module: http://build.prestashop.com/howtos/module/how-to-override-modules/.

Your problem is that ***getRow()*** function returns an array in which the keys are the fields fetched (id_currency and codfee(tax)), not the final value you're expecting. You have to use these values to calculate/convert the final amount you want, either in each of the function or after calling it. If you just have one currency on your store, you can change the ***getRow()*** function by ***getValue()*** and removing the ***id_currency*** field retrieval. It's still better to check the return value of the function (false if query failed), and make all the needed validation (currency matching between the one of the order and the one you want to display the information, ...).

Good luck

Comment: Hi Agnonym and thanks for reply, I am trying your simplest solution (change getRow in getValue and removing id_currency field) but is not working: the variable now results 0.00€.
Anyway the main file of the module "/modules/codpro.php" already extends the class PaymentModule and standard e-mails recognize these variables.
I'm still studying PHP and SQL and maybe this is too advanced for me, I really don't know what to do

Comment: Maybe the SQL query is wrong: does it look like that `return Db::getInstance()->getValue('SELECT codfee FROM ' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'orders WHERE id_order = ' . (int)$id_order);` ? You should try to dump the SQL query and execute it directly to see if you have the correct criterias and value

Comment: I think the query is correct because is the same for standard mails, is just a copy/paste.
This is /modules/codpro/codpro.php file [link](https://codepen.io/Felkio/pen/aaZWYO/)
(I don't find something similiar to codepen for php)

And the module works fine with standard e-mails.
Thanks for your help

Comment: Did you try to execute the query in your SQL database (PhpMyAdmin, Adminer, mysql, ...)?

Comment: Yes, I tried with
`SELECT codfeetax FROM ps_orders WHERE id_order = 57`
and it works

Answer (score 0):

You still can use the functions the module developer gave you:

1. Assign the query results to variables

   ```
   $codfee = $this->getCodFeeByOrderID((int)$params['id_order']);
   $codfeetax = $this->getCodFeeTaxByOrderID((int)$params['id_order']);
   ```
2. Get and assign the values you want to your smarty variables:

   ```
   '{total_fee}' => $codfee['codfee'],
   '{total_fee_tax}' => $codfeetax['codfeetax'],
   ```

Comment: Not working, 
I think the problem is that this module "can't see" at all "codfee" and "codfeetax" parameters, everytime the variable results in "0,00 €".
Maybe I have to add something in "codpro.php".
Thanks for your help anyway

Answer (score -1):

i had the same problem with a codfee module and solved modifying the ps_emailalerts.php class this way:

1. added the getCodFeeByOrderID function:

```
    public static function getCodFeeByOrderID($id_order)
        {
        return Db::getInstance()->getRow('SELECT id_currency, codfee FROM ' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'orders WHERE id_order = ' . $id_order);        
        }
```

2. in hookActionValidateOrder function, added to vars array:

```
    '{total_fee}' => Tools::displayPrice($order->codfee, $currency)
```

Comment: Have you edited an existing file of the PrestaShop core? That is not good, as you will loose this modification if you run an update

Comment: At present i haven't found a way to override the module class without breaking the mail sending functionality; the mailalerts module in PS 1.6 had the same problem. I have found a way to obtain the value that felkio was asking, by the way.

Comment: Are you sure about that? Have you read the accepted answer to this question which explains how to override that class?